# Resistivity of dielectric liquids

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, dielectric, electrochemistry

I was wondering if anyone here knows how the resistivity values of highly resistive dielectric liquids have been determined since the best commercial conductivity sensor I can find online only measures up to a resistivity of 10^10 ohm.cm. How has the published resistivity of liquids such as diesel, gasoline, transformer oils, etc which are in excess of 10^14 ohm.cm been determined? Some of these values are found in published studies many years ago as well.

Comment: Look at the articles (but maybe the old stuff is not available online). One guess is that they may have used RF (radio frequency) techniques to determine the loss angle.

Comment: Use a [Keithley 6517B electrometer](https://www.adler-instrumentos.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/1-6517B.pdf) as [described here](https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/47100631/PID4342121.pdf) or an older type of [electrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrometer).

Comment: @Pieter I've looked at the articles, but unfortunately I haven't found anything on how they measured the values.  Thanks for the suggestion into RF techniques, will look into it.

Comment: @Farcher I know the electrometers can display high resistivities, but i'm talking specifically about the sensors. I have a Keithley electrometer myself but you need to connect it to a sensor that can measure the resistivity.

Comment: Doesn't the research paper and its references give you that information eg [this one](http://file.yizimg.com/175706/2011120809002261.pdf)?

Comment: @Farcher thanks for that, looks useful. Will read it soon. The papers i found didn't mention the method no. But yh maybe i need to look harder.

Comment: I don't know about gasoline, but if there's no risk of explosion you just need a higher excitation voltage and/or a more sensitive ammeter and/or a sample with a bigger $A/\ell$ ratio.